# XAPK File Validation Failed

Tags: java, android

I'm uploading an app with an expansion file to Google Play. 
I've followed at least 4 guides and still nothing, I've used all the code on the DownloaderExample and also tested the expansion file locally. Which works, the problems now is when I try to download the Expansion File, I always get a "XAPK File Validation Failed." I've also never got a correct download of this.

If you could please help me, I would be very grateful.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using right Service and API key obtained from play store also make sure the file size specified in the code matched the Expansion files size. If you are using windows in that case right click on the expansion file and use "Size on disk" bytes as size.